# Exception Error: Invalid Method on Product Pages in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, porto-theme

**I recently installed the Porto Magento 2 Theme, it works however when a product is clicked on the below error occurs:**

[image]

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details::__

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details::__
<pre>#1 call_user_func_array() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:82]
#2 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->__call() called at [app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml:33]
#3 include() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:668]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:533]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:954]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:39]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:258]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:26]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:140]
#40 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:258]
#41 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

I have cleared and flushed the cache, re-indexed, recompiled and nothing seems to work, does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by re-uploading theme patch files and clearing browser cache